# Python types.MethodType()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why do I have to assign the result of types.MethodType() to an attribute before I use it via p.** in my example below. As I think, the method types.MethodType() has already bind the method onto the instance. Hope someone can help. Thanks a lot.

Here is my code:

```
import types


class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, newName):
        self.name = newName

    def eat(self, food):
         print("%s is eating %s" % (self.name, food))


    def getName(self):
         print("My name is %s" % self.name)


def main():
     p = Person("Peter")
     p.eat("Pork bean")
     types.MethodType(getName, p)  #p.getName = types.MethodType(getName, p)
     p.getName()


if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

[[image: Error result without assginment]]
[[image: No Error with assignment]]

Answer (score 8):

The following works to graft a method onto a class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value


def my_method(self):  # `self` is a plain name, not a reserved word or something.
    return 'Value via a grafted method is %s' % self.value

A.grafted = my_method

assert A('here').grafted() == 'Value via a grafted method is here'
```

Yes, a plain assignment works, equally well in Python 2 and Python 3.

Classmethods work the same way:

```py
class A:
  FOO = "foo of A"

def my_classmethod(cls):
  return (cls, cls.FOO)

# classmethod() is just a function, as any decorator.
A.grafted = classmethod(my_classmethod)
assert A.grafted() == (A, A.FOO)  # It worked.
```

Grafting a method onto an *instance* is harder but doable:

```
a = A('okay')
a.instance_patched = types.MethodType(my_method, a)

assert a.instance_patched() == 'Value via a grafted method is okay'
```

Here `types.MethodType(my_method, a)` creates a method *bound* to `a`.

Doing the following is elucidating:

```
print(my_method)
print(A.grafted)
print(a.instance_patched)
print(a.instance_patched.__func__)  # in python 2.x, .im_func
```

Comment: But how can you bind a function as a `classmethod` to a class, before you have an instance, in Python 3?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `getName()` is properly indented, on the same level as `eat()`.

There is no need for `types.MethodType()` for you case:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, newName):
        self.name = newName

    def eat(self, food):
         print("%s is eating %s" % (self.name, food))


    def getName(self):
         print("My name is %s" % self.name)


def main():
    p = Person("Peter")
    p.eat("Pork bean")
    p.getName()


if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Output:

```
Peter is eating Pork bean
My name is Peter
```

Furthermore:

```
types.MethodType(getName, p)
```

does do anything useful, because you throw away the return value.

Comment: Got your point, thanks. Make sense to me. Now I am clear about the assignment.

Answer (score -1):

Because `types.MethodType` doesn't mutate either the function or the instance, it just returns a new callable object which holds both the function and the instance.

(You seem to have been expecting "bind" to mean "mutate one of the objects to hold a reference to the other", and so it sorta makes sense that you thought of it as adding the function onto the instance, but the best way to think of "bind" is that it produces a new function copy which has the instance bound as its first argument.)